# how to set volume of media player between 1 to 100% in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am using video view, MediaPlayer and seek bar to control the volume of MediaPlayer but my question is how to give volume in percentage 1 to 100%?

Comment: use `AudioManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MediaPlayer [setVolume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setVolume(float,%20float)) method.
It gets 2 float values for left and right speakers and you can set the value for each between 0 to 1.0.
This means that if you want the volume to be 70% just call:

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.7, 0.7);
```